# Unmet Dependencies and sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1) error in DEBIAN

Tags: debian, gnome

I'm trying to install desktop environment on Debian in VM

gnome:

```
  apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

Throws Error:

```
 Reading package lists.. Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information.. Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get-f install' to correct these;
 The following packages have unmet Dependencies:
 gnome-desktop-environment : Depends: gnome(>=1:3.4+7+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed 
 liblouis2 : Depends: liblouis-data but it is not going to be installed 
 python-pyatspi2 : Depends: python-pyatspi(=2.5.3+dfsg-3) but it is not going to be installed 
 tracker-gui: Depends: tracker(=0.14.1-3) but it is not going to be installed 
 E:Unmet dependencies. Try apt-get install with no packages(or specify a solution).
```

Then tried this code

```
apt-get -f install
```

Errors were encountered while processing

```
   /var/cache/apt/archives/tracker_0.14.1-3_amd64.deb
   /var/cache/apt/archives/liblouis-data_2.4.1-1_all.deb
   /var/cache/apt/archives/libatk-adapter_2.5.3-2_amd64.deb
   /var/cache/apt/archives/libgail-common_2.24.10-2_amd64.deb
   /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pyatspi_2.5.3+dfsg-3_all.deb
 E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)
```

And also i have tried below code but failed

```
     # apt-get install aptitude tasksel
     # tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

Comment: Try `apt-get install`, as it suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increased SPace on device by using below command

```
# lvextend -L10G /dev/mapper/vg0-usr
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg0-usr
```

After that I execute

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

Sucessfully executed